# Write a script which other users can run to copy files into my directory which otherwise only has r-x for other users

Tags: permissions

I am new to unix permissions so I'll give as much relevant context as possible to avoid a possible xy post.

I'm on a multi-user system on which I do not have root access. I'd like to make a folder on my disk quota which other users can read and execute from, as well as sometimes add files to.

For example, if my username is `alice` and another user is `bob` and yet another is `charlie`, I'd like for `bob` to be able to read anything in my folder `assets` (which itself has subdirectories, so it execute permissions so that users can read the subdirectories). However, if `bob` has new assets he'd like `charlie` to be able to use, he would be able to add those assets to `assets`, but if `bob` does this without thinking, he might forget to give `r-x` permissions to those new assets, so `charlie` would be unable to use them (as well as `alice` would be unable to delete them!)

My idea for a solution to this problem would be to have a script owned by `alice` called `addAssets` which would copy an asset specified by args into `assets` *and* give it `r-x` permissions. Thus, `bob` could share his assets with everyone by running `addAsset path/to/asset`. Thus, it seems like this script would need write access to the `assets` folder but not the runner (so `bob` could not directly add to the `assets` folder and forget to chmod).

Maybe I'm just completely off-base here, but I would appreciate some clarification!

Comment: _"as well as alice would be unable to delete them!"_ -- that doesn't follow for regular files, as deleting a file is restricted by the write permission to the _directory_ holding the file, not the file itself. If Bob creates directories with files in them, and doesn't give write access to the directories, then that's different.

Comment: oh, I didn't know it was different, thanks! I'll update the post since in the real situation, users are adding subdirectories, and I just didn't know this wasn't the same :p

Comment: you'd need a setuid script here, or a setuid wrapper for a script, or something like sudo to allow those others to run that script as Alice. Setuid is rife with issues, since there's piles of stuff that get inherited from a parent process to child processes, and that can then cause vulnerabilities in the script. It might be better to have a common "staging ground" where the other users can copy their files into, and from where Alice's tools copy them off into the final destination. That way the others don't directly run anything under Alice's identity.

Comment: Either that, or have Alice run some process listening to a socket (or a fifo) which the others can then write their requests to

Comment: Could you elaborate on a "setuid script"? something like a bash script where the first line would be `su alice` and then somehow provide alice's password?

Comment: not exactly. ["setuid"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) is the thing where an executable program can be marked so that when it runs, it gets the "identity" of the user owning the program, not (just) that of the user running it. Programs like `su` or `sudo` are installed setuid, that's the way they can let you run programs as some other user (e.g. root). But like I said, programs that run like that have to be really careful with their environment (and I don't mean just the environment variables), and usually setuid doesn't work directly with scripts due to other reasons

Comment: Create a common `group` (say `ourgroup`) that `you`, `alice` and `bob` all belong to. Make `quota` and `assets` owned by `ourgroup` and make the files within either directory that need to be executed by all owned by `ourgroup`.  (e.g. `chown -R :ourgroup quota assets`) To ensure new files are created in the directories will also be owned by `ourgroup` set each directory setgid, e.g. `chmod 2770 assets` and the same for `quota`. Now all files created in either will be owned by `ourgroup` and any member can read, write, execute the files.

Comment: To create `ourgroup`, as root `groupadd ourgroup` and then add each user to the group, e.g. `gpasswd -a you ourgroup`, `gpasswd -a alice ourgroup`, and `gpasswd -a bob ourgroup`. Now log out/log in so group changes are seen in your environment. Permissions in comment above should be `chmod 2750 assets` and same for `quota` to have new files executable, but not modifiable, by all.

Answer (score 0):

This script might get you started.

Create a new user - let's call it: assets.

Assign the user a password.

Create a new group. Also called assets.

Add bob, alice and charlie to the group.

Make the assets group the primary group for bob, alice and charlie

Log in as assets and create a folder called assets

Set the permissions to meet your requirements.

I made it so the name of the group matches the name of the folder.
That's not necessary. It just makes it so everyone knows what that group is.

```
useradd assets
sudo passwd assets
group add assets
sudo usermod -a -G assets bob
sudo usermod -g assets bob
sudo usermod -a -G assets alice
sudo usermod -g assets alice
sudo usermod -a -G assets charlie
sudo usermod -g assets charlie
sudo - assets
cd .../assets ; cd ..
chmod 755 assets
```

Comment: Why not one group `ourgroup` where `op`, `alice` and `bob` are members and then set `assets` and `quota` setgid (e.g. `chmod 2770 ...`) so all can read, write and execute. (or `2750` for all read and execute. (but all need write to add new files in each)